# how to add `alt + mouse left click` as shortcut key in key map of android studio 3.0 (Ubuntu 16.4 LTS)

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, keymapping

I am trying to add `alt + mouse left click` as shortcut key in `keymap` but it only take `alt` or `mouse-click` and It takes nothing when try to add both.
Please help to resolve this issue.Below is the screen:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use not "*Keyboard shortcut*" but rather "*Mouse shortcut*" from a popup menu (number 2 at the picture):
https://developer.android.com/studio/images/intro/keymap-options_2-2_2x.png

Also by default on most linux desktop environments alt+mouse click is already assigned to window dragging. OS shortcuts have more priority. If it's the case for you then either use different shortcut in Android Studio or reassign OS shortcut (in this case Unity): https://askubuntu.com/questions/521423/how-can-i-disable-altclick-window-dragging
After that you should be able to use the shortcut in Android Studio

Comment: Thx for your help, but when i try to use **Add mouse shortcut** than it takes only mouse controller like Right click, left click and  mouse wheel.

Comment: I see. I've found this comment in JetBrains thread: _

Alt+drag is usually mapped to dragging a window in Linux window managers. If you want to use Alt+click shortcuts, make sure you disable that in system settings. _

Probably you can try to remap alt+mouse in unity if you don't use it. Otherwise it's impossible, since OS shortcuts have more priority